# Whole screen fades slightly when I add a layer... why?

Tags: adobe-premiere

Junior Adobe Premiere user here. Using Premiere Pro 2020 on Windows 10,
I am interviewing a person on Layer 1.
I added a picture in the upper right corner of the screen on Layer 2.  I just imported the image and dragged it to the timeline so it is on a new layer, then scaled it and repositioned it using the Effects Control panel. (I have a feeling this is my issue)
**It looks perfect in Premiere, but when I export to MP4, for the duration of the clip on Layer2, the whole of Layer1 fades slightly.**

Export settings: H.264, Match Source Bitrate, HW encoding, VBR, 1 pass, Target Bitrate: 10Mbps

Any ideas on what causes this and how to not fade the whole bottom layer?

Answer (score -1):

This was solved Ann Bens on the Adobe forums (https://community.adobe.com/t5/premiere-pro/layer-2-is-shading-layer-1-why/m-p/12061418#M348445).   **I disabled hardware encoding and this fixed my issue.**   This is of course just a band-aid as it does not address the real underlying issue but it does solve the problem.